# VS Code auto format spaces (both JS and TS)

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatter

```
render() {
    return (
      <Provider { ...stores }>
        <div className={ styles.auth }>
          { this.renderDevTools() } // not {this.renderDevTools()}
          <Layout/>
          <SnackBar/>
        </div>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
```

Is the above formatting possible in **VS Code** with no Prettier or other Beautifiers?